# Problems with setOptions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Im really sorry for asking such a newby question but I dont know what else to do.

I try to do the following

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./js/jquery.autocomplete.css">



  <script src="./js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="./js/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
           $("a").click(function() {

            alert('1');
            $("#producto").setOptions({max: 2}); 

            alert('2');
           });
 });
     </script>

</head>
<body >

    <a href="">Link</a>


     <input id="producto" name="producto" value="hola" />
</body></html>
```

It always give the same error that the object doesnt accept the method 'setOptions'.

What Im doint wrong !!?? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to initialize autocomplete:

```
 $("#producto").autocomplete("", {
    width: 320,
    max: 14,
    highlight: false
    //..Some Options
});
```

And then you can use .setOptions() and other methods.

PS:
[Autocomplete Jquery Plugin Page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete)  Says:

> Note (2010-06-23): This plugin is deprecated and not developed anymore. ITS FILES ARE NOT MAINTAINED BY THE JQUERY PROJECT, AND ARE NOT AVAILABLE AT JQUERY.COM.
>
> Its successor is part of jQuery UI:
>
> http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

You're not initialising the `autocomplete` plugin for this input field. Therefor `setOptions` is not defined.

Have a look a the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default) and especially the examples/sources of the autocomplete plugin.

e.g.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @faust Ah ok thanks for that. I was looking at the jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation by mistake. Makes sense now :)

Comment: Thanks so much for replying, but I think we are talking about different things, look at thishttp://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/setOptions, I have to grab some code from an old website that "works" and adapt it to mine. And when I copy a line with that function fails constantly

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the autocomplete method:

Maybe this will help you:

```
var ac = $('#query').autocomplete(options);
ac.setOptions({ zIndex: 1001 });
```

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/